# How to Load a Json data into dropdown Spinner Using Android Fragments

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, retrofit

I need to Show Registration Form With Spinner Using Fragments and get the data using Json

This is kind of register form. At the bottom we have change language button which will reset the form and will be shown in arabic / english.

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "TitleEN":"Kuwait",
      "TitleAR":"الكويت",
      "CurrencyId":1,
      "CurrencyEN":"Kuwaiti Dinar",
      "CurrencyAR":"دينار كويتى",
      "CodeEN":"KWD",
      "CodeAR":"د.ك",
      "Code":"965"
   },
   {  
      "Id":2,
      "TitleEN":"Emirates",
      "TitleAR":"الإمارات",
      "CurrencyId":2,
      "CurrencyEN":"Emirati Dirham",
      "CurrencyAR":"درهم إماراتي",
      "CodeEN":"AED",
      "CodeAR":"درهم",
      "Code":"971"
   },
   {  
      "Id":3,
      "TitleEN":"Saudi Arabia",
      "TitleAR":"السعودية",
      "CurrencyId":3,
      "CurrencyEN":"Saudi Riyal",
      "CurrencyAR":"ريال سعودى",
      "CodeEN":"SAR",
      "CodeAR":"ر.س",
      "Code":"966"
   }
]
```

Comment: What have you done up until now?

Comment: which spinner has to show the json data ? there are multiple spinners. code, country city area. which one has to show the data?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**.I assume you have followed the first 3 steps from this [question][1] 
and will start from the following
**Step 1**
Add spinner in xml

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/spinner_title" />
```

**Step 2** 
In `ApiInterface` Class add the following code

```
@GET("/app/app.asmx/GetCountries")
Call<List<Country>> getCountry();
```

**Step 3**
Create new model class by name `Country`

```
public class Country {

@SerializedName("Id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("TitleEN")
@Expose
private String titleEN;
@SerializedName("TitleAR")
@Expose
private String titleAR;
@SerializedName("CurrencyId")
@Expose
private Integer currencyId;
@SerializedName("CurrencyEN")
@Expose
private String currencyEN;
@SerializedName("CurrencyAR")
@Expose
private String currencyAR;
@SerializedName("CodeEN")
@Expose
private String codeEN;
@SerializedName("CodeAR")
@Expose
private String codeAR;
@SerializedName("Code")
@Expose
private String code;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitleEN() {
    return titleEN;
}

public void setTitleEN(String titleEN) {
    this.titleEN = titleEN;
}

public String getTitleAR() {
    return titleAR;
}

public void setTitleAR(String titleAR) {
    this.titleAR = titleAR;
}

public Integer getCurrencyId() {
    return currencyId;
}

public void setCurrencyId(Integer currencyId) {
    this.currencyId = currencyId;
}

public String getCurrencyEN() {
    return currencyEN;
}

public void setCurrencyEN(String currencyEN) {
    this.currencyEN = currencyEN;
}

public String getCurrencyAR() {
    return currencyAR;
}

public void setCurrencyAR(String currencyAR) {
    this.currencyAR = currencyAR;
}

public String getCodeEN() {
    return codeEN;
}

public void setCodeEN(String codeEN) {
    this.codeEN = codeEN;
}

public String getCodeAR() {
    return codeAR;
}

public void setCodeAR(String codeAR) {
    this.codeAR = codeAR;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

}
```

**Step 4** 
find view in activity or fragment and add call the request and get response and add the response in spinner adapter.`Initialize` a string list out side the `onCreate` method

```
List<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
APIInterface apiInterfacePages;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    apiInterfacePages= PageApiClient.getRetrofit().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<List<Country>> getCountry = apiInterfacePages.getCountry();
    getCountry.enqueue(new Callback<List<Country>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Country>> call, Response<List<Country>> response) {
            countryList = response.body();
            for (int i = 0; i < countryList.size(); i++) {
                codes.add(countryList.get(i).getCode());

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTime = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, codes);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapterTime);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + countryList.get(i).getTitleEN(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Country>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    }
```